# Subprocess only allows one input

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to communicate with an interactive command line application, but after I send the first command to the application, all other input seems not to be communicated to the subprocess. Can anyone show me where my mistake is?

Here's the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty
import time


class Prolog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Opens a subprocess running swi-prolog and reads all the header stuff that it writes
        """
        self.prolog = Popen(r"C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        # This thread runs in the background as long as the program is running it enqueues all the output from Prolog
        self.q = Queue()
        t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(self.prolog.stdout, self.q))
        t.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        t.start()

        out = True
        while out:
            out = self.get_line()

    def get_line(self):
        """
        read line without blocking
        :return: the next line in the output, else False if no more output
        """
        try:
            line = self.q.get(timeout=.1)  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
        except Empty:
            return False
        else:  # got line
            return line

    def send_query(self, query):
        """
        Sends a query to the Prolog shell
        :param query: string containing the query to be sent to the prolog shell
        :return: None
        """
        query = query + "\n"
        query = bytes(query, encoding="utf-8")
        self.prolog.stdin.write(query)
        self.prolog.stdin.flush()

    def get_output(self):
        output = self.get_line()
        if not output:
            return False
        else:
            return output[:-2]

    def query(self, query):
        output = []
        self.send_query(query)
        temp = self.get_output()
        print(temp)

        while not temp:
            time.sleep(.1)
            temp = self.get_output()

        output.append(temp)

        while not temp == b'true.' and not temp == b'false.':
            self.send_query(";")
            temp = self.get_output()
            print(temp)

            while not temp:
                time.sleep(.1)
                temp = self.get_output()

            output.append(temp)

        print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Prolog()

    p.query('[\"GCD.pl\"].')
    p.get_output()
    p.query("permut([a, b, c], X).")
```

The problem comes during the second call to p.query. The command doesn't seem to be passed to the shell at all, so there is never any output, so the program just gets stuck in the "while not temp" loop in the query method.

Comment: You could simplify this by interacting with the coprocess directly from your main thread and not use a thread with a queue.

Comment: Any tips on how to get that to work? That was how I started out, but given the fact that this is an interactive application, I don't always know exactly how many lines of output I will get, and since a call to read before there is any new output will wait for the application to create more output, this is the only way I could think of to avoid hangs.

Comment: Even though I'm not a big fan of it, the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) is probably what you're looking for.